# Assignment of values to class objects in C++

Tags: c++

I am sorry if it is duplicated question, but i didn't find a discussion of exactly this question. So, i am learning C++ and i don't understand the following issue with the assignment of values to class objects. I have this implementation of the class **T**:

```
class T
{
    int aInt;
    double aDouble;

    public:
    T():aInt(0),aDouble(0.){}

    T(int my_aInt, double my_aDouble):aInt(my_aInt), aDouble(my_aDouble){}

    T(int my_aInt):aInt(my_aInt), aDouble(0.){}

    T(double my_aDouble):aInt(0), aDouble(my_aDouble){}

    void set_aInt(int my_aInt){
        aInt = my_aInt;
    }

    void set_aDouble(double my_aDouble){
        aDouble = my_aDouble;
    }

    int get_aInt(){
        return aInt;
    }

    double get_aDouble(){
        return aDouble;
    }
};
```

I want to create the objects of this class and assign some values to them. I can do it in this way:

```
T tt1(-1, 5.), tt2(-1), tt3(5.);
```

and it works fine. Now i want to change the values assign to object **tt1**. I know that i can do it like this:

```
tt1.set_aInt(-3); // gives aInt = -3, aDouble = 0
tt1.set_aDouble(6.); // gives aInt = 0, aDouble = 6.
```

and it also works fine. But it seems there is another way to do it:

```
tt1 = -3; // gives aInt = -3, aDouble = 0
tt1 = 6.; // gives aInt = 0, aDouble = 6.
tt1 = (-3, 6.); // gives aInt = 0, aDouble = 6. - Why?
```

My first question is: Is `tt1 = -3;` equivalent to `tt1.set_aInt(-3);` and is it a good practice? The second question is what is wrong with `tt1 = (-3, 6.);` and why it sets value of **aInt** equals to **0** instead of **-3**?

Comment: Define an assignment member function explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should mark the single argument constructors `explicit`, because defining a single argument constructor also creates an implicit conversion from the argument type to the constructed type in C++, which is typically not desired.

```
tt1 = -3;
```

is thus equal to:

```
tt1 = T(-3);
```

i.e. it uses copy/move assignment. In the second case, the `(-3, 6.)` is just parenthesis around the statement `-3, 6.`, where `,` is the sequence operator. The statement thus evaluates to `6.`, and the implicit conversions using the `double` constructor is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `tt1 = -3` this is equivalent to

```
T temp(-3);
tt1 = temp;
```

In C++, a constructor that takes a single argument acts as an implicit conversion operator. So the compiler looks at `tt1 = -3` and sees that it can convert -3 to a `T` type using your constructor in a temporary variable and then use the default `=` operator to assign the value to `tt1`. The assignment to `6.` works similarly except that the constructor that takes a single double is used. If you prepend the constructor with `explicit` it will not be used for conversions like this.

When you type `tt1 = (-3, 6.)` you are invoking the comma operator. In C/C++, `(x,y)` evaluates to `y`, so this is really equivalent to `tt1 = 6.`

Answer (score -4):

it is good to provide set_aInt so that you can track where the value passes on to in class where as it is equal as to pass tt1 = -3; while (-3,6) is passed to class T Probably the override as accepted the integer value but it erased it and passed the double value 6. due to which you faced a problem. While you initialize separately two instances of allocation take place and allocate value, But in single initialization the updated value which overrides previous value goes into the class